# How to setup an Indy custom TIdIOHandler?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to use a custom `TIdIOHandler` for my Indy TCP client and I don't know how to set it up. I create a new IOHandler class, I registered with `TIdIOHandler.RegisterIOHandler`, and then I use `TIdTCPClient.CreateIOHandler` with my new handler reference. Now, when I try to write to the `TIdTCPClient.Socket` I get "Abstract error" exception... Do I need to configure other things besides my example ?

```
  TIdEnhancedIOHandler = class(TIdIOHandlerSocket)
  public
    function Acknowledge(Command: Cardinal = 0): Boolean;
  end

{this is a client in a thread}
constructor TMyTCPClient.Create(const AHost: String; APort: Word);
begin
 inherited Create;
 FreeOnTerminate:= True;
 TIdEnhancedIOHandler.RegisterIOHandler;
 TCPClient:= TIdTCPClient.Create;
 TCPClient.CreateIOHandler(TIdEnhancedIOHandler);
 TCPClient.ConnectTimeout:= 1000;
 TCPClient.ReadTimeout:= -1;
 TCPClient.Host:= AHost;
 TCPClient.Port:= APort;
 RetSuccess:= False;
 RetMessage:= 'Unknown error.';
end;

procedure TMainClient.Execute;
var CMD: Cardinal;
begin
 TCPClient.Connect;
 TCPClient.Socket.Write(CMD);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the Indy Help I understand that ...

The help is old, and has outdated information.

> I must use `CreateIOHandler` and specify my custom IOHandler class.

You can do that, but you don't actually need to.  You can simply assign an instance of your custom class directly to the `TIdTCPClient.IOHandler` property, before calling `TIdTCPClient.Connect()`, eg:

```pascal
TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create;
TCPClient.IOHandler :- TIdEnhancedIOHandler.Create(TCPClient);
...
```

> I do that and I get an exception which says that this class is not installed.

That means Indy's internal `GIOHandlerClassList` does not contain any class types that derive from the class type you specify to `CreateIOHandler()`.

> How cand I install it ? The variable `GIOHandlerClassList` that holds the list is private...

You would need to call the public `RegisterIOHandler()` or `SetDefaultClass()` class method on your custom class type at runtime, such as in your unit's `initialization` section, eg:

```pascal
initialization
  TIdEnhancedIOHandler.RegisterIOHandler();
```

However, the only thing in Indy that actually uses `CreateIOHandler()` is `TIdSimpleServer`, so there is no need to "register" your custom class in this situation.

On the other hand, `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` does call `TIdIOHandler.MakeDefaultIOHandler()` if no `IOHandler` is assigned, and that uses `GIOHandlerClassDefault`, which is set by `TIdIOHandler.SetDefaultClass()` (which also calls `RegisterIOHandler()`).  So, if you want `TIdTCPClient` to create an object of your custom class type for you, you would need to call `SetDefaultClass()` at least, eg:

```pascal
initialization
  TIdEnhancedIOHandler.SetDefaultClass();
```

Either way, `RegisterIOHandler()`/`SetDefaultClass()` should be called only one time, such as at program startup.

---

**UPDATE**: you are getting an abstract error because you are deriving your class from `TIdIOHandlerSocket`, which is an *abstract* class, as it does not implement the `ReadDataFromSource()` and `WriteDataToTarget()` methods that are declared as `abstract` in `TIdIOHandler`.  You need to derive your class from `TIdIOHandlerStack` instead, which derives from `TIdIOHandlerSocket` and implements those methods.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing the question when you wrote the answer. I used `SetDefaultClass` and the handler is successfully created... but now, when I try to read/write to TCPClient.Socket I get an exception with message "Abstract error"

Comment: Great, that's it ! Thanks !

Comment: But I don't see may `Acknowledge` function in `TCPClient.Socket` or `TCPClient.IOHandler`...

Comment: The `IOHandler` property is a `TIdIOHandler`, and the `Socket` property is a `TIdIOHandlerSocket`. `Acknowledge()` is not a member of either class. You would have to type-cast to access it: `TIdEnhancedIOHandler(TCPClient.IOHandler).Acknowledge(...)` or `TIdEnhancedIOHandler(TCPClient.Socket).Acknowledge(...)`.  In this case, it might make more sense to have `TIdEnhancedIOHandler` be a [class helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)) rather than a descendant, then you won't need the type-cast: `TCPClient.IOHandler.Acknowledge(...)`